# Given an array of indices, get the appropriate item from a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

If I have an array like so:

```js
let arr = [
  [],
  [],
  [
    1, 2, ["a"]
  ]
]
```

I want to get an item from the array given an array of indices.

Here is an example:

```js
let arr = [
  [],
  [],
  [
    1, 2, ["a"]
  ]
]

function findByIndex(arr, indices) {
  // code here
}

findByIndex(arr, [2, 2, 0])
// returns `arr[2][2][0]` which is "a"
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: `arr[2][2][0]` returns `"a"`, right @Mamun ?

Comment: I am trying right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Array.prototype.reduce()` to walk along the chain of indices of the nested array (or object) that you supply as the second argument of the reduce call:

```js
let arr = [[],[],[1,2,["a"]]];
let res=[2,2,0].reduce((a,c)=>
 a[c],arr);
console.log(res);
```

In each cycle of `.reduce()` you will get one level deeper until you reach the final value.

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on your indices array to grab each index from your incidences array while updating the `acc` to be the value at that index, eventually leading to your final value:

```js
const arr = [ [], [], [ 1, 2, ["a"] ] ];

function findByIndex(arr, indices) {
  return indices.reduce((acc, i) => acc[i], arr);
}

console.log(findByIndex(arr, [2, 2, 0]));
```

If you want to go the recursive route, you can use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pull the first index out from your indices array as well as grab the remaining indices using `...rest`. If there are no more indices to search (when `rest.length` is 0), then you can stop your search and return the current value at the current index. If there are more items to search (rest.length has items), then you can recursively call your findByIndex function with the current element at index `i` from your array (`arr[i]`) and the remaining indices (`...rest`):

```js
let arr = [ [], [], [ 1, 2, ["a"] ] ];
function findByIndex(arr, [i, ...rest]) {
  return rest.length ? findByIndex(arr[i], rest) : arr[i];
}

console.log(findByIndex(arr, [2, 2, 0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a recursive function and if indices length is 1 then return the `corresponding` element from the `arr`. Else get the first element from the arr using the element at the 0 index of `indices`. Then use shift to remove the used index and recall the same function with new values

```js
let arr = [
  [],
  [],
  [
    1, 2, ["a"]
  ]
]

function findByIndex(arr, indices) {
  if (indices.length === 1) {
    return arr[indices[0]]
  } else {
    const newArr = arr[indices[0]];
    indices.shift();
    return findByIndex(newArr, indices)

  }
}

console.log(findByIndex(arr, [2, 2, 0]))
```